# install laravel on hostgator shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How to install laravel php framework on hostgator shared hosting?
- PHP Version 5.2
- AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php in .htaccess file

My Problem:
Cannot install composer using SSH : $ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php 
Getting error : The phar extension is missing
Install it or recompile php without --disable-phar

Your Php(5.2.17) is too old, you must upgrade to PHP 5.3.2 or higher.

Comment: 1.  Install The phar extension. 2. upgrade to PHP 5.3.2 or higher

Answer (score 4):

Hostgator supports PHP 5.4+. Try using that.

See: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/hardware-software/php-5-4

> PHP 5.4 is available on shared hosting accounts provisioned after May
>   1, 2013 using by adding the following code to your .htaccess file.
>
> `AddType application/x-httpd-php54 .php`

Answer (score 2):

[Laravel 4 has server requirements here:](http://laravel.com/docs/installation#server-requirements)

- PHP >= 5.3.7
- MCrypt PHP Extension

Since your host has PHP 5.2 - you cannot use Laravel 4. Consider changing hosts, or using Laravel 3.